# jquery ajax getting response from url of other domains

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have tried the following code, but the **AJAX** call does not get a response.
Please tell me why I am getting a failed **AJAX** call.

```
   $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType:"html",
    url: "http://www.example.com",
            //url = any url other than the same domain
    success: function(response,status){
        alert(status);
        //$("#search_text").val("");
        //$("#search_results").html(msg);
        //setTimeout('refresh()',2000);

        //alert($("#sw_hdr"));

    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use AJAX to communicate across domains. Well, you can but jQuery's Ajax function won't do it. Look up XSS attacks for more information

Here is a link for reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Answer (score 0):

You can still use JSONP: [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)
Note that the remote page must support this format.
(as does the google api for instance)

Comment: JSON also does not get AJAX response from other domains

Comment: What I meant is the JSONP technique where the corresponding server serves the requested data via a script-tag. for these crossdomain requests are possible. the returning code will invoke a callback (that has to be submitted before) and submit the requested data like so: `yourcallback( {data1:1111} );`